# SaxonApiException: The supplied node has been schema-validated, but the XPath expression was compiled without schema-awareness

Tags: java, xpath, schema, saxon

I just upgraded from Saxon EE 9.6.0.4 to 9.8.0.12 and now on the following code I get the exception on the call to setContextItem()

```
XPathExecutable exe = xPath.compile(query);
XPathSelector selector = exe.load();
selector.setContextItem(xmlDocument);
```

I create the xpath object as follows:

```
void ctor(InputStream xmlData, InputStream schemaFile, boolean preserveWhiteSpace) throws SAXException, SchemaException, SaxonApiException {

    this.rootNode = new XpathDataSourceNode();
    Map xsdNamespaces = new HashMap();
    XMLReader reader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
    //reader.setEntityResolver(runtime.);

    InputSource xmlSource = new InputSource(xmlData);
    SAXSource saxSource = new SAXSource(reader, xmlSource);
    Source schemaSource = new StreamSource(schemaFile);
    Configuration config = createEnterpriseConfiguration();
    config.addSchemaSource(schemaSource);
    Processor processor = new Processor(config);
    SchemaValidator validator = new SchemaValidatorImpl(processor);

    DocumentBuilder doc_builder = processor.newDocumentBuilder();
    if(!preserveWhiteSpace)         

doc_builder.setWhitespaceStrippingPolicy(WhitespaceStrippingPolicy.ALL);
doc_builder.setSchemaValidator(validator);
XdmNode root_node = doc_builder.build(saxSource);
XPathCompiler compiler = processor.newXPathCompiler();

declareNameSpaces(root_node, compiler);

this.xmlRootNode = root_node;
this.xPath = compiler;
```

What do I need to do different in this case?

thanks - dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set

```
compiler.SchemaAware = true;
```

The check (and error message) were introduced because earlier releases were producing incorrect results in such cases: with the `SchemaAware` property set to false, the optimizer assumes that all atomized content will be `xs:untypedAtomic`, which is not correct if the input document has been put through schema validation. Changing the optimizer to remove this assumption would have led to performance degradation for all users of non-schema-aware XPath, that is, the majority of users.

Note that if you're going to query typed data using XPath, then it's best if the XPath compiler has access to the schema, so it can actually take advantage of the fact that the data is typed. However, the scope for this is limited, because the XPath API has no equivalent to the `XQueryCompiler.ContextItemType` property in XQuery, which allows the type of the context item to be declared statically. So in practice the XPath compiler isn't going to be able to make many static inferences (or detect many errors) based on schema information.